# Accessing my files from Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows. I have seen several guides giving me the same advice as to how to mount my harddrive with my Windows files in it in Ubuntu but it doesn't ever show my drive when I click the home folder. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have NTFS file system on your windows partition. If not, please do not try to use the ntfs-3g driver!

Here is a pointer to an excellent document on the configuration of fstab config file:

[FSTAB configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

fstab is a config file in which partitions are named which should be mounted at boot time. In Linux, partitions are mounted into a folder, thus you have to create a line similar to this for your windows partition:

```
/dev/hda2 /media/windows ntfs-3g defaults,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

This line makes Linux mount the device /dev/hda2 (replace this with the device of your windows partition) to the folter /media/windows (replace this by the folder where you wish your windows files to appear). I suggest to keep it in /media/... and then create a nautilus bookmark for simple access.

Last point: Warning! Be careful when editing your /etc/fstab file. A corrupt line in there could make your ubuntu unbootable!